# What does it mean to "Weep for Tammuz"?

Tags: ezekiel, idolatry

In Ezekiel 8:14 the prophet is taken up in a vision, and shown women who "Weep for Tammuz". The passage doesn't explain what it means, although they are engaged in some form of idolatry. My bible footnotes tells me it is a "fertility god". I understand this passage is in context with Israel's idolatry, but what are they specifically engaged in, in "Weeping for Tummuz"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good question. The information available is very complex, so I have gleaned the most relevent information to answer the question. To begin, @lasersauce made the correct observation that

> He [Tammuz] appears to have been a god of the spring, and the myth regarding
>   him told of his early death and of the descent of Istar, his bride, into
>   the underworld in search of him.

In this regard, [Becking and Dijkistra (1996)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HXVeRwQYzjMC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=tammuz%20ritual%20mourning&source=bl&ots=JGlWdlW_df&sig=RhEiPIjLTi2iS9-QeK4uH7UsTmI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nA20U97_PJKM7AbbjICoBA&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=tammuz%20ritual%20mourning&f=false) provide important historical details. That is, there are similarities with the death of the Canaanite God Baal and Tammuz written in the *In the Ras Shamra* texts. In one of the studies the writer observes that

> The mourning for Baal as a vegetation deity in eclipse suggests the weeping for Tammuz, also a vegetation deity, by the woman of Jerusalem in the sixth month ([Ezek 8:14](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezek%208%3A14&version=NASB)) and, more directly, the public mourning for Hadad-Rimmon (the Canaanite Baal) in the valley of Megiddo ([Zech 12:11](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Zech%2012%3A11&version=NASB)). (1).

Additional sources are [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PqItlkqrrxQC&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=death%20of%20baal%20Tammuz%20ras%20shamra&source=bl&ots=9baEeJSE9o&sig=UZt40Q5f__4sMyC_UDNOuOf2puo&hl=en&sa), as well as [this post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/what-is-the-story-behind-mourning-for-hadad-rimmon-in-zechariah-1211).

In summary, the sources indicate several parallels between Tammuz and the Canaanite god Baal.

Comment: Thank you for your energetic search! I can see that there are numerous complications in examining this passage-but the common theme appears to be a fertility/spring ritual cult, a vestige of the Caananite festivals.

Answer (score 5):

Weeping for Tammuz was a 40 day mourning period for a pagan sun deity that which God castigates Israel for whoring after in Ezekiel 8:13-16. Today this period of mourning is called Lent.

> The reasons for celebrating our major feasts when we do are many and
>   varied. In general, however, it is true that many of them have at
>   least an indirect connection with the pre-Christian [pagan] feasts
>   celebrated about the same time of year — feasts centering around the
>   harvest, the rebirth of the sun at the winter solstice (now Dec. 21,
>   but Dec. 25 in the old Julian calendar), the renewal of nature in
>   spring, and so on.

(The New Question Box - Catholic Life for the Nineties, copyright 1988 by John J. Dietzen, M.A., S.T.L., ISBN 0-940518-01-5 (paperback), published by Guildhall Publishers, Peoria Illinois, 61651., page 554.)

Comment: Hi Irv, welcome to BH.SE, and thanks for your answer! Consider providing links or sources for others to be able to reference (something like [this](https://www.bibletools.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Topical.show/RTD/cgg/ID/805/Tammuz.htm) would be great).

Comment: Ezekiel 8:13-14

“Turn you yet again, and you shall see greater abominations that they do. Then he brought me to the door of the gate of YHWH’s house which was toward the north; and, behold, there sat women weeping for Tammuz. Then said he unto me, Have you seen this, O son of man?”
Ezekiel 8:16

And he brought me into the inner court of YHWH’s house, and, behold, at the door of the temple of YHWH, between the porch and the altar, were about five and twenty men, with their backs toward the temple of YHWH, and their faces toward the east; and they worshipped the sun toward the east.

Comment: Ezekiel 8:16

And he brought me into the inner court of YHWH’s house, and, behold, at the door of the temple of YHWH, between the porch and the altar, were about five and twenty men, with their backs toward the temple of YHWH, and their faces toward the east; and they worshipped the sun toward the east.

Comment: Jeremiah 7:18-19

“The children gather wood, and the fathers kindle the fire, and the women knead their dough, to make cakes to the queen of heaven, and to pour out drink offerings unto other gods (on Easter), that they may provoke me to anger. Do they provoke me to anger? says YHWH: do they not provoke themselves to the confusion of their own faces? Therefore thus says the YHWH ELOHIYM; Behold, my anger and my fury shall be poured out upon this place.”

Comment: The reasons for celebrating our major feasts when we do are many and varied. In general, however, it is true that many of them have at least an indirect connection with the pre-Christian [pagan] feasts celebrated about the same time of year — feasts centering around the harvest, the rebirth of the sun at the winter solstice (now Dec. 21, but Dec. 25 in the old Julian calendar), the renewal of nature in spring, and so on.

Comment: Source: The New Question Box - Catholic Life for the Nineties, copyright 1988 by John J. Dietzen, M.A., S.T.L., ISBN 0-940518-01-5 (paperback), published by Guildhall Publishers, Peoria Illinois, 61651., page 554.

Comment: Note that Lent is a moveable observance, connected to and preceding the festival of Easter. Easter is celebrated on a day specified only by the Roman Catholic Church, and not the Bible, and is fixed based on the sun and the Spring or Vernal equinox.

Comment: Irv there is no evidence that the Tammuz mentioned in verse 13 is the same deity worshiped in 16. Can you support your claims that Tammuz is a sun god and that it is origin of the Lent?

Comment: How about if instead of you pronouncing there is not evidence of such, instead take the time to read the entire of Ezk and figure this out for yourself?

Comment: How about if instead of you pronouncing there is not evidence of such, instead take the time to read the entire of Ezk and figure this out for yourself?  Look up each name, and think; Fertility to the ancients came in Spring when the rays of the sun impregnated the earth and caused life to spring forth. Just so coincidentally exactly 9 months later the son of the Sun god is born on exactly Dec. 25th. This when all Christian theologians pretty much agree Jesus was not born on this date.

Comment: John 1:14 makes it pretty obvious when the Messiah was born;  
And the Word became flesh  and tabernacled (fixed His tent of flesh, lived awhile) among us; and we  saw His glory , such glory as an only begotten son receives from his father, full of grace and truth

Comment: Moseh told the children to once a year observe a festival called Tabernacles (Greek) and in Hebrew Sukah.  Take note, the feast of Sukah is a day where Israel (covenant children) are directed to camp out in tents with God under the stars. Now what is the millennial kingdom to consist of? God and man camping out (tabernacle) once again.

Comment: The evidence is plain in front of your eyes, every time Israel whored after the gods of their gentile neighbors God pronounced the act as an abomination. Easter is so obviously pagan in nature that even the folks who incorporated the right into the Christian religion readily admit the same. Going backwards Easter (Eastra), Ishtar,  Asherah, Semiramis.  All represent the goddess of spring, the mother of god, the queen of the universe. Just as the RCC calls the mother of their Jesus, the queen of the universe, the mother of god.

Comment: Are you going to claim God wants us to observe a pagan feast day and jettison His Passover, Unleavened Bread, First Fruits all of which He declare to be eternal days to be called out?

Comment: There is no possible way and not do I care to convince you or anyone else what is Yahowah's will. His will if found in His Towrah, and nowhere else. Reading is not understanding. To understand one must know Yahowah through His Towrah, this will require reading it from the Hebrew, yes that is a very daunting task, but don't blame Him. Yahowah did not direct Moseh to translate His word into Greek, back to Hebrew, Latin, and many revisions of the English, with a host of copy edits under the Masorites in 1100 CE and the RCC in the 3rd and 4th century CE.

Comment: If you have faith that you're on the right path then I'm not here to convince you otherwise.  His will is only found in His Towrah, and nowhere else. Might want to look at the many quotes made by the Ma'aseyah (messiah) all are from Towrah, what prophecy do you think he was fulfilling? Did he fulfill all prophecy and all written about him? If yes, then why come again? If no then Christianity is a false faith as not the smallest letter has been changed in Towrah.

Comment: Towrah is not the possession of the Jewish religion or Rabbis It was given to any one who desires to come to know Yahowah and be counted a child of God. Towrah is not law, it is the teaching, instruction, and guidance of Yahowah to those who would be counted His children. There is no word in Towrah that can even be translated to mean 'obey' in reference to Yahowah. He is father not LORD. 

Understanding the will of God will answer you question as to what He wants His children to observe starting this Friday eve.

Comment: Irv, please put your meaty comments into your answer. Comments are just for comments and may wind up being deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to J. R. Dummelow, Tammuz was

> a deity worshipped both in Babylonia and in Phoenicia—the same as the Greek Adonis. He appears to have been a god of the spring, and the myth regarding him told of his early death and of the descent of Istar his bride into the underworld in search of him. The death of Tammuz symbolised the destruction of the spring vegetation by the heat of summer, and it was celebrated annually by seven days of women’s mourning in the 4th month (June–July), which was called Tammuz. This superstition had been introduced into Jerusalem. (*[A Commentary on the Holy Bible](https://www.lds.org/manual/old-testament-student-manual-kings-malachi/chapter-26?lang=eng)*, pp. 497–98.)

Here is a an [additional source](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NopUi53PC0YC&pg=PA70&dq=death%20of%20baal%20Tammuz%20ras%20shamra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UZ20U9SPFMuoyASbzYLIBg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Tammuz&f=false), covering most of the same information, but more recently printed, although not as plainly laid out.

Comment: Dummelow’s book was published in 1909, when the study of ancient Babylonia was still in its infancy. In the mean while an enormous number of texts from Babylonia have been excavated and lots of good studies of Babylonian religion in general and Tammuz in particular are available, in real books, and even on the internet. What is actually the point of pasting something from an out-of-date book from 1909?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's fair to exclude sources based on their antiquity (esp. in dealing with ancient scripture) but I didn't find any contradictory information, so went with the source I felt covered it well and in brevity.

Answer (score 3):

Tammuz was a pagan god or idol that the women were weeping for on the north side of the temple. According to T.Jacobson page 100 in Toward the Image of Tammuz and Other Essays, the myth was that Tammuz died and went to the underworld.

The visions of the temple that God gave to Ezekiel in chapter eight actually show what was taking place in Jerusalem at the temple. The leaders of Jerusalem were worshiping images that represented pagan gods(8:7-12). Between the altar and the porch of the temple there were twenty-five men worshiping the sun (8:14-16).There was an idol in the temple court that angered God (8:3-5).

The people had forsaken God, forgot God, and God would destroy the temple. Only a small remnant would escape and Ezekiel cried out for mercy (9:1-8).Ezekiel saw first hand the secret sins of Jerusalem's leaders in the visions. Intercession would not stop the destruction of Jerusalem (14:12-20).

This judgement would come upon those who worshiped idols, sexually abused others,cheated people financially, slandered people, oppressed the orphan and widow(22:1-12) Gary Smith, An Introduction to the Hebrew Prophets. pg. 262-271.

Comment: This is a substantial answer and I have up-voted it. But would you be able, for the sake of completeness, to give links to your references in the first and last paragraphs, please ?

Comment: Nicely answered, Sam, and welcome to the forum. Links are nice when available, but your page references are certainly acceptable. I'd suggest that unless you're paraphrasing due to length, make sure to indicate direct quotes from your sources by starting each line with the character denoting a blockquote, which is >.

Answer (score 1):

Tammuz was an actual person. He was not a god/deity though he was worshiped like one after his death. He was the son of Nimrod. And this is how it goes: Nimrod was descended directly from Noah- Noah had a son named Ham. Ham had a son named Cush. Cush married a woman named Semiramis and they had a son named Nimrod. When Cush died, Nimrod married his mother Semiramis. When Nimrod died Semiramis was pregnant. When she had the baby, she named him Tammuz. Semiramis believed Tammuz was Nimrod reincarnated. 
**Nimrod was a powerful king. He was the one building the tower of Babel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  We are glad you stopped by and hope you stick around. When you have a chance, check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour).  In particular, be sure to read the section on what constitutes a good answer and revise your post to either cite references that back your position or to more thoroughly explain how you get this interpretation from the text itself.  Please note that "showing your work" is [required](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/735/what-kind-of-site-do-we-ultimately-want-to-have/777#777) on this Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Lizzie Wow! This flies in the face of most commentaries. Can state your sources, and perhaps quote them in your response? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Tau, I'm just seeing your comment. Sorry for such a late reply. SURE! I will definitely site my sources. I didn't know that was required on this site and got a friendly note from the moderator as well asking me to site sources. I only have 1 source for this and that is the Bible. But I will get all of the verses and timelines together and repost <3

Answer (score 1):

I would not refer to what was told about these gods as a myth.  Psalms 82 they were real.  Tammuz was a master at love poems and he wrote love poems to Ivanna aka Isthar, asthoreth.  They are the same poems Solomon captured that people have in the bible and say its of the Almighty One. But its from a god to a goddess that existed in those days.  My guess on why the women weep for him was that as us women are today when it comes to men who display a certain level of sensuality, songs and lyrics and we put them in the god status and actually worship them This is idolatry. It was the fallen of Mesopotamia idolatry for these gods that fell. There was and is today nothing new under the sun neither the behavioir of people

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. We are glad you stopped by and hope you stick around. When you have a chance, check out the site tour at http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour. In particular, be sure to read the section on what constitutes a good answer and revise your post to either cite references that back your position or to more thoroughly explain how you get this interpretation from the text itself. Please note that "showing your work" is required on this Stack Exchange -- http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/735/what-kind-of-site-do-we-ultimately-want-to-have/777#777

Comment: Welcome to the forum. It's important here to support your assertions. Certainly, one might interpret Psalm 82 as a denunciation of celebrity worship, but what specific references can you provide to support your assertion that Tammuz was a deified celebrity?

Comment: Psalm 82 is not referring to the Chaldean "idols" which are not real and do not have any power to save or resurrect life. Asaph was a musician in the Levitical priesthood of Israel. In context of Psalm 82:1,6 the term is "elohim", or those who ruled unjustly and judged over Israel. The council of 70 if you will which Jesus spoke to in John 10:34, He quoted from this Psalm in pointing out the Sanhedrins' hypocrisy.  You are taking verses out of Psalm 82 from their original context and applying them to "false idols" which the time and again YHVH exposes as mere constructs of men.